# Custom where method

Tags: c#, linq

I have a project which I can't use `System.Linq`, so I am trying to create a cutsom Where method which works exactly same as linq, how can I do that?

```
var x = y.ToList().Where(t => t.Title != "Foo");
```

**SOLUTION 1**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var x = y.ToList().Where<Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode>(x => x.Title != "Foo");
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> filter)
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            if (filter(item))
                yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

*NOTE : .NET v 2.0*

Comment: http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/edulinq/

Comment: What have you tried? [The source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs) might be a good place to start

Comment: There's no point of ToList before Where.

Comment: Why you can't use linq? It's just built-in into the framework, with no extra dependencies

Comment: @Alejandro: Maybe he is working with old code on an old framework that doesn't have it in the framework.

Comment: Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNodeCollection

Comment: SPNavigationNodeCollection is an IEnumerable (not a generic one). Change to: x = y.OfType<Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode>().Where(x => x.Title != "Foo");

Comment: still same also tried OfType<IEnumerable<Microsoft.SharePoint.Navigation.SPNavigationNode>> too

Comment: @Mert: You really should be asking a separate question about this specific usage since it is quite different from the main question here about how to implement `Where` yourself. And then you could ask more clearly with exception message and code to reproduce it more easily visible than just in comments. That and you'll get more visibility on your problem as a new question than as a question in comments.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> filter) 
{
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (filter(item))
            yield return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sayse I haven't read the blog you mention, but about the only thing I'd do differently to this (and indeed have as part of several answers, and my pre-linq code that took a delegate it defined because `Func` didn't exist yet) was to rename `filter` to `predicate`. (If it was for use outside of its own assembly I'd have null checks before passing to a separate private method). This code is the obvious implementation.

Comment: If they don't have Linq, but they do have lambdas, they are presumably using .NET 3.0. You'll have to add `public delegate TResult Func<T, TResult>(T arg);` to define `Func` so that this can be used.

Comment: they use .NET v2.0, so I guess Func also doesn't work?

Comment: You can implement `Func` in 2.0 easy enough. The lambda won't work though so `t => t.Title != "Foo"` will have to be replaced with `delegate(SomeType t){return t.Title != "Foo";}`.

Answer (score 1):

Write a Loop that determines your result

```
List<YourObject> List = new List<YourObject>();
List<YourObject> Result = new List<YourObject>();
for (int i = 0; i < List.Count; i++)
{
    if (List[i].Title != "Foo")
        Result.Add(List[i]);
}
```

Comment: right - but in this case it seems to fit his needs

Comment: Yeah, it quite possibly will. but the question does say "exactly same" so I thought it at least worth a comment noting that. It wasn't a "this is a bad answer" type comment, just a "here's an additional note" type comment. It may have been a bit terse though and come across badly in which case I apologise for any misunderstanding I may have caused.